# 5V short circuit with GND

Tags: gpio

When using mpu6050, vcc wire short circuit with GND like 10 times, and cause shutdown every time, raspberry pi is still working now, Mpu6050 can't detect when typed sudo detect y -l, there is nothing at address 0x68, should i buy a new raspberry pi

Comment: Well, if Rpi is still working, then very likely mpu6050 is fried. So I would suggest to buy a mpu6050.

Comment: I would make sure the cabling is really correct now. Switch off everything and wait 1 minute or so, to make sure the mpu6050 is reset as well. It's unlikely that the mpu dies due to a short in the power lines.

Answer (score 1):

Shorting 5V with GND only really stresses the power supply, and, depending on the Pi model, the polyfuse. After a cooling down time, everything should work again.

However, it's pretty much impossible to know what else was shorted in your setup. mpu6050 is a 3.3V device, so applying 5V on any of its pins has a good chance of destroying it.